# Get Count of selected files in Telerik Upload

Tags: telerik-mvc

I need to get a count of all selected files using Telerik MVC Upload Control. Can anyone tell me how can i do that. I tried code like this.

```
var count = e.files.length;
```

But its counting always as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this  code

```
[function onSelect(e) {    
var selectedFiles = e.files.length;
totalFiles += selectedFiles;
   }

function UploadRemove(e) {

totalFiles--;
    if (totalFiles > 0) {
    // Write true block code here.
}
else if (totalFiles == 0) {
// Write your false block code here.

}
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in your upload event handler:

```
upload: function (e) {
   // File Count:
   var fileCount = this.wrapper.find(".k-file").length;

   // File Index:
   var uid = e.files[0].uid;
   var file = this.wrapper.find(".k-file[data-uid='" + uid + "']");
   var fileIndex = file.index();
}
```